# Uncaught Reference Error in typescript (VS 2019)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am trying to call a function onClick but it keeps giving me an uncaught reference error saying my function was not defined. Any ideas ?

```
 <a href="#" title="AxesButton" onclick="axesclick()">Axes</a>
```

```
axesclick() {
    this.comp.axesname();
  }
```

Comment: Downvoted because the question shows no research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `eventListener` in the `constructor` and then call the function. You cannot call the class method directly.

I would recommend the below approach.

**Example:**

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    this.axesclick = this.axesclick.bind(this);
    document.getElementById("Axes").addEventListener("click", this.axesclick);
  }

  axesclick() {
    console.log("Hi");
  }
}

new SomeClass();
```

```html
<a href="#" title="AxesButton"  id="Axes">Axes</a>
```

Comment: It does not work I tried that, it says "unexpected token. A constructor...etc. was expected

Comment: this.axesclick gives an error because it says axesclick does not exist

Comment: tried it. TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null, this is the error

Comment: you should load the javascript code after the html, place your script tag at the end of the body.

Comment: my js code is in a separate ts file, any fixes for this particular scenario ?

Comment: You have to compile the ts file and add it in the html file using script tag